# creating minimum distance between two points in a random list of created points. having issues creating my list of distance values

Tags: python-3.x

This is a function within a large class Point. The goal of this problem is to create an empty list of distance values (def calc_distance has already been created) and then iterate it through the list of random coordinate values created and find the minimum distance value as well as its index in the list of random coordinate values. Thank you in advance!

```
import random

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.d = 2
        if self.z != 0:
            self.d = 3

    def print_coordinate(self):
        print("The coordinates are ({}, {}, {})".format(self.x, self.y, self.z))

    def calc_distance(self, pt):
        isinstance((x, y, z, pt.x, pt.y, pt.z), float)
        return ((((pt.x - self.x) ** 2 + (pt.y - self.y) ** 2) + (pt.z - self.z) ** 2) ** 0.5)


#d1 = Point(4.12, -234.4, 34.1)
#d2 = Point(-63.2, 34.6, -23.1)
#d1.print_coordinate()
#d2.print_coordinate()
#d1.calc_distance(d2)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({str(self.x)}, {str(self.y)})'

#Q6

    def float_N(self, num_point, dimension, lower_bound, upper_bound):
        points = []

        for _ in range(num_point):
            if dimension == '2-D':
                point = Point(random.uniform(lower_bound, upper_bound), random.uniform(lower_bound, upper_bound))
                points.append(point)
            else:
                pass
                # if 3-D coordinates
        return points

#print(float_N(100, '2-D', 0, 100))

# Q7 generate 100 Point class instances

#a = Point(0, 0)
#list1 = a.float_N(100, '2-D', 0, 100)
#print(list1) #= 100 Point class instances

#Q8 closest pt from list to (50, 50)

    def closest_pt(self):

        dvalues = []

        list1 = a.float_N(100, '2-D', 0, 100)
        min = (((pt.x - self.x) ** 2 + (pt.y - self.y) ** 2) ** 0.5)

        for _ in range(len(list1)):
            dvalue = (((pt.x - self.x) ** 2 + (pt.y - self.y) ** 2) ** 0.5)
            # or dvalue = Point.calc_distance(self, pt)
            return dvalue
        dvalues.append(dvalue)
        try:
            if dvalue < min:
                min = dvalue
        except NameError:
            min = dvalue



a = Point(0, 0)
b = Point(50, 50)
print(a.float_N(100, '2-D', 0, 100)) #= 100 Point class instances ---> Q7 <--- (list1)
list1 = a.float_N(100, '2-D', 0, 100)
print("Minimum Point is ", min(list1, key=dvalues))
return min((a.float_N(100, '2-D', 0, 100)), key=dvalues)
print(b.closest_pt(dvalue))
```

I keep getting dvalue is not defined.
I am having difficulty retrieving the list of distance values. I am able to get the random coordinate values, but not their distance values between point (50,50) so I cannot work further and index the min distance value.

Comment: Thanks for your question, can you be a bit more specific? Where you say 'dvalue is not defined' which function is this error being thrown? If you could remove any code irrelevant to this error it will be easier for the community to trace the issue.

Comment: The error should be at `print(b.closest_pt(dvalue))`. At any point before that in this code `dvalue` is only defined inside of functions, not at the outer scope. You also have a `return` on the line right before that...? Please check your code for formatting and indentation.

Comment: Hi Bill the Lizard, I have tried other indentations of return and pycharm deems them as unreachable code.

Comment: Hi Josh Sharkey, the error message I receive is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sarah/PycharmProjects/a02_wozniak.py/Projects/a04_Wozniak.py", line 146, in <module>
    print(b.closest_pt(dvalue))
NameError: name 'dvalue' is not defined


I have a lot of unnecessary code I am sure. This is my first python course without any previous coding experience so I am struggling some.